# Serialization of ActiveRecord::Base descendants don't work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I have a string field `data` in `SerializeTest` model and I want to store JSON presentation of another ActiveRecord model in it. Does not matter what I do it keeps storing `NULL` to database.

The same code works when `SerializeableObject` is a plain object, not a descendant of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

```ruby
class SerializeTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, SerializeableObject
end

class SerializeableObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def load(data)
      new JSON.load(data)
    end

    def dump(obj)
      obj.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how to reproduce it

```ruby
s = SerializeTest.new
s.data.foo = 'test'
s.save
s.reload
s.data.foo # should be 'test' but equals nil
```

Migrations

```ruby
class CreateSerializeTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :serialize_tests do |t|
      t.string :data
    end
  end
end

class CreateSerializeableObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :serializeable_objects do |t|
      t.string :foo
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S. It was working fine in Rails 3 but does not work in Rails 4.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using? With 4.0.0 and basic setup, everything works as expected (`#<SerializeTest id: 1, data: #<SerializeableObject id: nil, foo: "test">>`)

Comment: I'm using 4.2.10

Comment: @MrShemek I've pushed my project with instructions how to reproduce in the readme https://github.com/luckyjazzbo/rails4-serialize-example

Comment: it looks like the SerializeableObject has to be saved in DB first. After that, when it is "attached", you can modify it (`s.data.foo = 'test 2'`). When saving the main object (`s`), the data attribute will be updated and SerializeableObject (save in db) will remain the same. However, I still do not know why this happens.

Comment: this does not help much.. the whole point of this field is storing data of not yet ready objects

Comment: I have tested your code with different Rails versions and it looks like a bug in Rails that was fixed in 5.0.0.